# Mangled name even after extern c

Tags: c#, c++, dllimport

I have included a C++ library in my C# project and i am calling one of it's method.

Earlier I was having the mangling problem then read about extern c and applied it to C++ method.

Then tried calling it like below:

```
[DllImport(@"F:\bin\APIClient.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr logIn2(IntPtr a, IntPtr b, IntPtr c, IntPtr d, IntPtr e, IntPtr f, int g);
```

But still I am getting Entry Point exception.

C++:

```
 APICLIENT_API char* logIn2(const char* a, const char* b,const char* c,const char* d,const char* e,const char* f, int g);
```

And if i use entryPoint in DLLImport then it works fine:

```
[DllImport(@"F:\bin\APIClient.dll", EntryPoint = "?logIn2@CAPIClient@API@@QAEPADPBD00000H@Z", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern IntPtr logIn2(IntPtr a, IntPtr b, IntPtr c, IntPtr d, IntPtr e, IntPtr f, int g);
```

Why even after using extern c I have to give this Entry point to make things working.

Comment: can you show the C++ method declaration?

Comment: Are you using extern c only in header files ? From what you're saying it seems that you declared as extern C in your headers, but the object still gets compiled in the .cpp as being cpp (thus mangled). Try opening the dll and see if you have your C prototypes exposed.

Comment: @MichaelCMS:: can use extern "C" in class methods? It gives error if we use extern C in header. So we are using it in implementation.

Comment: @NitinRawat, you should give us a declaration of your `APICLIENT_API` macro.

Comment: Are you talking about class method? Class method names are always mangled.

Comment: @AlexFarber It means if it is a class method then I have to use Entry point at any cost in my DLLImport.

Comment: It is better to write C or C++/CLI wrapper for C++ library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The decorated C++ name is **not** a problem.  It is actually very desirable, it automatically saves you from having to diagnose a very difficult runtime crash when the C++ code is changed and the function signature is altered.  Since there now will be a mismatch and you get an easy "Procedure not found" error message instead of a corrupted call stack that is quite undiagnosable.

The **much** bigger problem, and the reason that `extern "C"` doesn't work, is that this is an *instance method* of the CAPIClient class.  It uses the __thiscall calling convention, required to pass a valid *this* pointer.  You can't get that from pinvoke, it requires allocating memory for the C++ object and calling the CAPIClient constructor.  Only a C++ compiler knows how to do that correctly, only it knows the correct amount of memory to allocate.  So you can't pinvoke, you have to write a C++/CLI wrapper.

The normal mishap when you pinvoke an instance method of a C++ class is a hard crash, typically reported as an AccessViolationException.  Triggered when the instance method tries to access another other instance member of the C++ class through the invalid *this* pointer.  Only a static C++ function can be correctly pinvoked.  Since you didn't seem to have triggered an exception (yet), there's some hint that the function should have been *static* in the first place.

Comment: The C++ method is not static and yes the visual studio crashes when we are writing any code inside the C++ method that is calling and other class method.

Comment: No, it is not Visual Studio that crashed.  It was your C++ code.  That should be a little obvious by now.  Otherwise easy to see by enabling unmanaged code debugging.  I already gave you the answer, you have to write a C++/CLI wrapper so you can properly construct the C++ object.

Comment: As you said "Only a static C++ function can be correctly pinvoked." Now we have made the methods of the C++ static but still we are getting the issues.